# Is there a way to create groups for an Amazon Mechanical Turk Requester task?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I am a part of a group trying to create an Amazon Mechanical Turk Requester task. We'd like to either have a group account or have multiple accounts with access to the same project. I've been looking around and cannot find a way to do this. Is it possible to make this happen without sharing a single account?

Answer (score 2):

This may not be perfect, but if you're an MTurk API customer, you can use Identity and Access Management (IAM) to have a single account (with a credit card on file) but provide multiple sets of API credentials (AWS Access Keys and Secret Keys) that you can provide to reach person/group that wants to use the account. This isn't a perfect solution because:

- It is only applicable to the MTurk Application Programming Interface (API)
- There aren't quotas or controls to limit spending on one person vs. another
- Each account can still access each other's HITs (it isn't separate accounts)

You can learn more about IAM support in MTurk here: https://blog.mturk.com/introducing-mechanical-turk-api-support-for-iam-credentials-8f2de8cd6afb

There is not currently a way to do something similar in the Requester Website (requester.mturk.com).

Hope that helps a little.